# How to copy values over to another kind of class

Tags: c++, polymorphism

I use the `ofxCvBlob` class from openframeworks. Let's say i get one object:

```
ofxCvBlob blob = blobs.get(i);
```

I have my own class which extends `ofxCvBlob`:

```
class ofxDTangible : ofxCvBlob {

}
```

Suppose i have 1 object of type `ofxDTangible`:

```
ofxDTangible tangible;
```

And i want it to get the values from `blob` then how can this be done?

Comment: I think you have to clarify what you want to do, and how `blob` relates to `tangible`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't understand your problem correctly but if `ofxCvBlob` has appropriate copy construction

```
class ofxDTangible : ofxCvBlob 
{
public:
    ofxDTangible() {};
    ofxDTangible(ofxCvBlob& base) : ofxCvBlob(base) {};
}

ofxDTangible tangible(blob);
```

Comment: The question is asking how to make an appropriate copy construction.

Comment: your code works great. But i don't understand it. Why does `ofxDTangible(ofxCvBlob& base) : ofxCvBlob(base) {};` not need a body?

Comment: @clankill3r For initializing member variables in construction you can use `Member initializer list`. for information see http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initializer_list